# Spring batch understanding chunk processing

Tags: spring-batch

I have total 8 records in table, from which 6 are eligible for jpareader when spring batch calls read. Now I have page size and chunk size set to 1 for testing. Expecting that when job runs, it should make 6 read calls, and then it should process them one by one and write them one by one. But actually what happens is it just calls read 4 times (from logs I can see reading page 0...1 like that) and processes 4 from which one is filtered out because doesnt match criteria for writing and then it just updates 3 records and job is marked completed successfully.

Like this job needs to be run 3 times in order to process all records. Something is not clear to us. Tried to understand chunk processing but I think chunk is only to aggregate result to make write call..after that I expect read and process should continue.

With this test, we are confused on what to set for chunk size for production, if we set to large number it will require more memory (heap).

Comment: What do you mean by page size? Could you post the relevant part of your configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see the confusion. The `pageSize` parameter of the `JpaPagingItemReader` has nothing to do with the `chunkSize` (or `commit-interval`) of the chunk-oriented step.

If you take the `JpaPagingItemReader` and use it outside a chunk oriented step with a pageSize = 4, it will fetch 4 items at a time (ie, per page). Now those 4 items can be processed in chunks of 2 for example, and you will have two chunks per page. The `JpaPagingItemReader` will read the first page (list of 4 items) and then return items from that list each time a call to `read` is made by the chunk-oriented step. Here is an example with a `pageSize = 4`, `chunkSize = 2`, `totalItems = 8` and a chunk listener:

```
ChunkListener.beforeChunk
Reading page 0
Reading item1
Reading item2
Writing item1
Writing item2
ChunkListener.afterChunk
ChunkListener.beforeChunk
Reading item3
Reading item4
Writing item3
Writing item4
ChunkListener.afterChunk
ChunkListener.beforeChunk
Reading page 1
Reading item5
Reading item6
Writing item5
Writing item6
ChunkListener.afterChunk
ChunkListener.beforeChunk
Reading item7
Reading item8
Writing item7
Writing item8
ChunkListener.afterChunk
ChunkListener.beforeChunk
Reading page 2
Reading item = null
ChunkListener.afterChunk
```

I created a [sample app](https://github.com/benas/sandbox/tree/master/issues/so53490144) with this configuration so you can play with it and see how things work.

Hope this helps understanding the chunk-oriented processing model when used with a paging item reader.

Comment: Wow, I haven't seen this before. Now I will play with your sample app. But irrespective of that why in my case it didn't process all items in one job run (with many reads and chunks). Thanks.

Comment: I can reproduce my problem with your sample. I added one more record with first name as Tom (at begining in data, very first record). I changed query to "from Customer where firstName='Tom'" and added ItemProcessor where I set firstname to upper case. Now changed page size and chunk size to 1. If I run application, it just processes very first record and job is getting completed and second Tom is not getting converted to upper case. I am expecting to process both Tom one by one.

Comment: Added a record "Tom Cruise" to the data set at the beginning + updated the query/processor, still working as expected:

`MyJob.beforeChunk
Reading page 0
Reading customer = Customer[id=1, firstName='Tom', lastName='Cruise']
Writing customer = Customer[id=1, firstName='TOM', lastName='CRUISE']
MyJob.afterChunk
MyJob.beforeChunk
Reading page 1
Reading customer = Customer[id=8, firstName='Tom', lastName='Hanks']
Writing customer = Customer[id=8, firstName='TOM', lastName='HANKS']
MyJob.afterChunk
MyJob.beforeChunk
Reading page 2
Reading customer = null
MyJob.afterChunk
`

Comment: I can see only these major changes, if this works, I will create branch of your repo to submit.@Component
public class MyItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Customer,Customer> {
    @Override
    public Customer process(Customer customer) throws Exception {
            customer.setFirstName(customer.getFirstName().toUpperCase());
            return customer;
}
} and return steps.get("step")
    .<Customer, Customer>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
    .reader(itemReader(null))
    .processor(myItemProcessor)
    .writer(itemWriter())
    .listener(chunkListener())
    .build();

Comment: also chunk and page size set to 1

Comment: yes I added a processor to uppercase the name (as you see in the output) and set  page size and commit interval to 1. Still working as expected.

Comment: try this branch , I can see only one getting processed. https://github.com/springusr/sandbox/tree/test/so53490144

Comment: added a comment on github.

Comment: Thank you, that is it. I will try soon. Huh.. appreciate.

Comment: It is working, I will set that to false, I guess that works fine , creating new entity can be complicated for complex entities.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - I don't see https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-lab/tree/master/so53490144 exists now. Could you please share link ?

Comment: @JeffCook I updated the answer with the correct link.